# using php to compare mysql columns to SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two databases, one online (mysql) and one in my office (SQL Server) which I would like to compare and update where a value is different.

I am using php to connect to the SQL Server database and run a query to retrieve the information, then connecting to the Mysql database running a query. Then I need to compare the two queries and update where necessary.

Is there somewhere I can look for tips on how to do this, I am sketchy on PHP and struggling really.

This is as far as I have got-:

```
<?php
$Server = "**server**";
$User = "**user**";
$Pass = "**password**";
$DB = "**DB**";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($Server, $User, $Pass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($DB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $DB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.code, ps.onhand";
$query .= "FROM products p with(nolock)";
$query .= "INNER JOIN productstockonhanditems ps with(nolock)";
$query .= "ON ps.ProductID = p.ID";
$query .= "WHERE ps.StockLocationID = 1"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$get_offlineproduct2 = mssql_query($query);

mysql_connect("**Host**", "**username**", "**password**") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
$get_onlineproducts = mysql_query(SELECT w.ob_sku, w.quantity
FROM product_option_value AS w
ORDER BY ob_sku) 
or die(mysql_error());

//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

I am looking to compare the value p.code to w.ob_sku and whenever they match copy the value of ps.onhand to w.quantity so the online database has the correct quantities from the office database.

My question I guess is how close am I to getting this right? Also am I doing this the right way, I don't want to get so far and realise that i am just wasting my time...

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are taking the right approach: extract data brom both databases, then compare the results. What step are you struggling with? Retreiving records from MS SQL? From MySQL? Comparing the two result sets? (notice the syntax error in your call to `mysql_query()`: this function expects a string, quotes are missing)

Comment: Thanks Yak, I'm glad I'm on the right track and thanks for the syntax error heads up! It is the next part of the query I am having problems with, comparing the two and updating the stock value...

Comment: I just realised you do not really want to "compare" values from both databases, but instead update some values in the one with the values from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to fetch any record from MySQL, since you actually want to update it.

I would do something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT p.code, ps.onhand FROM (...)';

// execute the SQL query and return a result set
// mssql_query() actually returns a resource
// that you must iterate with (e.g.) mssql_fetch_array()
$mssqlResult = mssql_query($query); 

// connect to the MySQL database
mysql_connect("**Host**", "**username**", "**password**") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error());

while ( $mssqlRow = mssql_fetch_array($mssqlResult) ) {
    $mssqlCode = $mssqlRow['code'];
    $mssqlOnHand = $mssqlRow['onhand'];
    mysql_query(
        "UPDATE product_option_value SET quantity = $mssqlOnHand WHERE ob_sku = $mssqlCode"
       // extra quotes may be required around $mssqlCode depending on the column type
    );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Yak, I will test this tomorrow and report back! Is there a way to test this query without actually updating?

Comment: You could echo or log the `UPDATE` query instead of running it.

Comment: Hi Yak, I am getting an error.  Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near 'p'. (severity 15) in update.php on line 25

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in update.php on line 25

Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in update.php on line 31

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near 'p'` => you have a SQL syntax error. Everything fails in cascade after that.

Comment: Thanks Yak, I inserted some spaces in the ms sql query, seems ok but I'm not sure it is functioning correctly as it completes very quickly...I think I might have to work through the query again....